# Why is setHeader not working within process function but out of function

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a small camel project in which i read files from filesystem and process them in my route. 
Inside the process function i set

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("tc.GIARO.item.ids",simple("TC00000021"));
```

and afterwards the .to() function is not working. 
But when I set this outside the process function like

```
.setHeader("tc.GIARO.item.ids", simple("TC00000021"))
```

the .to() function recognizes this header and works.

if i .log() straight after .process() or the .setHeader() function it logs out in both ways..

Somebody knows why this happens?

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("file://" + path + "?preMove=inprogress&move=.done")

            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    String myFilename = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileNameOnly");
                    String[] tcid = myFilename.split("-");

                    String filename = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFilePath");
                    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)));

                    exchange.getOut().setBody(content, String.class);
                    exchange.getOut().setHeader("tc.GIARO.item.ids", simple("TC00000021")); //whether here                      
                }
            })
             .setHeader("tc.GIARO.item.ids", simple("TC00000021")) // or whether here
             .log("${header.tc.GIARO.item.ids}")
             .to("tc://" + ip + "/tc?tcMethod=getItemAndRelatedObjects&tcUser=" + user + "&tcPass=" + pass
                    + "&tcSessionKey=1");
}
```

Comment: Difficult to say without the rest of your route. I would however suggest that you change from getOut() to getIn() as it is the in-portion that you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setHeader in In message (not Out message).
Don't create a new Message (using `exchange.getOut().setSomething`)

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("file://" + path + "?preMove=inprogress&move=.done")

            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    String myFilename = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileNameOnly");
                    String[] tcid = myFilename.split("-");

                    String filename = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFilePath");
                    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)));

                    exchange.getIn().setBody(content, String.class);
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("tc.GIARO.item.ids", simple("TC00000021")); //whether here                      
                }
            })
             .setHeader("tc.GIARO.item.ids", simple("TC00000021")) // or whether here
             .log("${header.tc.GIARO.item.ids}")
             .to("tc://" + ip + "/tc?tcMethod=getItemAndRelatedObjects&tcUser=" + user + "&tcPass=" + pass
                    + "&tcSessionKey=1");
}
```

Comment: no it's not working... i also set "exchange.getOut().setBody(content, String.class);" which is working

Comment: Are you creating an new Out message ? Please, post the code of your `process` method.

Comment: See my edit : if you do `exchange.getOut().setBody(content, String.class);`it will create a new Message. Changing the IN message directly is possible in Camel as it doesn't mind. Camel will detect that the Exchange has no OUT message
and therefore use the IN message instead. See here : http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Comment: I'm unsure if it helps but I also suggest changing from simple() to constant(). If for nothing else it probably adds more overhead than is needed.

Comment: It doesn't work with getIn()... if I look afterwards it gives me empty values:
** .log("ItemId '${header.tc.GIARO.item.ids}' with revision '${header.tc.GIARO.rev.id}' description will be changed to '${body}'"); **
becomes
**[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - file://C:%5Cgru_temp%5Cinbox] INFO route1 - ItemId '' with revision '' description will be changed to ''**

Also tried "constant" but also not working